# Should I use cpu utilization or system load?

Tags: cpu-usage, load-average

I use `ffmpeg` to transcode H265 video to H264 stream.  The computer seems over capacity while pulling video from two cameras.

[image]

The machine is equipped with a 8-core `i7-7700T`.  My question is, shall I use CPU utilization (460.7%, 331.7%) or load average to evaluate CPU requirement for the transcoding task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load average show the number of processes run and wait in interval of 1,5 and 15 minutes (in 5 seconds frame)

CPU utilization give you the processors usage for particular process. Which is more meaningful in your case. You can sum this value for all `ffmpeg` processes.

If you want to get CPU utilization for entire system in specific moment you can use command like:

```
vmstat 1 2
```

(get the second line as first is for average from start of the system)

Answer (score 0):

**You should use load average to evaluate CPU requirement.**

To interpret CPU usage and Load Average numbers you should take into account

- total number of physical cores in a system (all CPUs)
- is HyperThreading enabled
- in Linux Load Average also includes processes in uninterruptible sleep state waiting for I/O
- CPU usage and Load Average numbers interpretation depends on number of logical cores
- you should check per core CPU statistics to be more accurate. In `top` press '1' for per core stat and 't' to turn graph bars.

i7-7700T have **4 physical cores**, and with HT enabled **8 logical cores** https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97122/intel-core-i77700t-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html

**CPU usage, %**
show utilization - percent of time when CPU is not idle and execute tasks scheduled by OS scheduler.

Each core may used up to 100% so max usage capacity of 8 cores is 800%.

So two ffmpeg processes utilize all 8 cores at 460.7% + 331.7% = 792.4%.

Whole CPU stat in this line

```
%Cpu(s):  19.9 us,  0.7 sy,  78.1 ni, 1.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
```

Here 19.9% of user space time + 78.1% of nice time = 98% of CPU usage by userspace program.

So CPU cores are busy at 98% by all of userspace processes with 79,2% executing two ffmpeg processes.

Because transcoding is a CPU bound task, you will almost always have close to 100% utilization on any CPU.

**Load Average**
is an average, over some period, number of threads executed + number of threads waiting to be executed.

One core execute one thread at a time slice.
8 cores can execute 8 threads at a time slice.

System overloaded if Load Average > number of logical cores.
This means the OS scheduler cannot allocate the next time slice to some threads due to the busy cores and puts them in a run queue to wait for execution.
Second number in Load Average = 25.65 on system with 8 cores means:

- in average 8 threads executed during last 5 minutes
- in average 17.65 threads waits in run-queue during last 5 minutes

**So system overloaded on 17.65/8*100=220.6%.**

Comment: I think CPU utilization might be more appropriate, as if a thread is waiting for I/O, it does not use CPU resource, but is still counted in load average, right?  In case of rtsp transcoding, although it is CPU bound, network I/O is still a factor which may pump up load average.  I calculated total CPU usage of ffmpeg according to [this post](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/total-process-cpu-usage), they uses about 400%~650% of CPU, which is about 6 out of 8 cors on i7-7700.